# How to get selector hyperlink inside nav ,ul,li in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hyperlink tag inside nav,ul,li .can anybody tell how to get hyperlnk selector .How to check which hyperlink is click .if apps is selected i need to print apps and home is selected i need to print home

```
<nav class="test-nav">
<ul class="test-list">
<li class="test-list-item>
 <a href="test-list-item-menu> Apps </a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item>
 <a href="test-list-item-menu> Home</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item>
 <a href="test-list-item-menu> Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item>
 <a href="test-list-item-menu> Title</a>
</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').on('click','nav ul li a',function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
})
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check which hyperlink is click

Just find it inside li

```js
$("li.test-list-item").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).find("a").text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="test-nav">
<ul class="test-list">
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Apps </a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Home</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Title</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```js
$("li.test-list-item").click(function(){
  $("#div1").html($(this).find("a").text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="test-nav">
<ul class="test-list">
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Apps </a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Home</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="test-list-item">
 <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Title</a>
</li>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this selector:** `nav.test-nav ul.test-list li.test-list-item a.test-list-item-menu'` to select directly the links.

*Using the classes we can close the scope of the selector.*

```js
$('nav.test-nav ul.test-list li.test-list-item a.test-list-item-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="test-nav">
  <ul class="test-list">
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="test-list-item-menu"> Apps </a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="test-list-item-menu"> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="test-list-item-menu"> Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="test-list-item-menu"> Title</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event from the `nav` to child `a` using `on`

```js
$('.test-list').on('click','a', function(e) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log($(this).text().trim())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="test-nav">
  <ul class="test-list">
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Apps </a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="test-list-item">
      <a href="test-list-item-menu"> Title</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```